# How to keep focus on terminal when running python script?

Tags: python, firefox, terminal, focus

I have a python script that needs to open 6000 images one by one for me to manually annotate them.

These images are links so I need to open the browser to see them. However when I do this, focus switches form the terminal running the script to the browser, forcing me to re-click the terminal to change focus. this is really tedious, I need to be able to keep focus on the terminal.

I am on Ubuntu, and the browser is firefox, I open the browser as follows:

```
for url in urls:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
    pattern = -1
    while not (pattern == 0 or pattern == 1):
        print('Enter 0 for no pattern, 1 for pattern')
        pattern = input()
```

Comment: Can you just tell Ubuntu to keep the terminal window on top (via right-clicking its title bar)?

Comment: Keeping the terminal on top does not keep focus.

Comment: Then maybe I don't understand what you want to do. Can you clarify what you're doing in the browser and what you're doing in the terminal?

Comment: Terminal I type. Broswer just lets me the images. i.e what I want is to never have to touch the mouse as I browse and annotate the images.

Comment: I think you don't need to click your mouse to just see the image? They just show in the browser. Why you need to click?

Comment: Does [`webbrowser.open(url, new=2, autoraise=False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) do what you want?

Comment: When firefox is opened, focus switches from terminal to image. If I want to type in the terminal again I have to switch focus back to terminal, which can be done by clicking the temrinal (and by alt tabbing if you have the shortcut). I don;t want to do this, i just want focus to remain on the terminal.

Comment: @Chris no, autoraise just keeps focus on the last opened tab, not on the terminal.

Comment: You are not using `selenium` are you?

Comment: My bad I thought the webbroswer module used selenium under the hood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't understand why you have this question as `selenium` won't change your focus at all.

```
from selenium import webdriver

b = webdriver.Firefox()
b.get("https://www.google.com")
b.get("https://whatever")
```

Test this code, and you will find it doesn't change your focus at all.